# Room doesnt update

Tags: android, android-room

i want to update element from listview with room but it doesnt work.
Adding and deleting works properly but update doesnt 
here is my code

```
@Insert
    public void addZakazi(Zakazi zakazi);

    @Query("select * from orders")
    public List<Zakazi> getZakazi();
    @Delete
    public void deleteZakazi(Zakazi zakaz);
    @Update
    public void updateZakazi(Zakazi zakazi);
```

Code of fragment where i push button and it calls another fragment

```
update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Zakazi zakaz=getItem(position);
                String cNam=zakaz.getClName();
                String o=zakaz.getOrder();
                int pric=zakaz.getPricec();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("price",pric);
                bundle.putString("cName",cNam);
                bundle.putString("order",o);
               updateFragment uf =new updateFragment();
               uf.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, uf);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Code of called fragment where update must be done

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup parent,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_order_layout,parent,false);
        Cname=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.clients_name_up);
        price=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.price_edit_up);
        order=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.order_edit_up);
        updateB=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.updateB);
Bundle bundle=getArguments();
String ord=bundle.getString("order");
String clnam=bundle.getString("cName");
int pri=bundle.getInt("price");
Cname.setText(clnam);
price.setText(String.valueOf(pri));
order.setText(ord);
updateB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       String cn=Cname.getText().toString();
       String orderr=order.getText().toString();
       int p=Integer.parseInt(price.getText().toString());

        Zakazi zakazi=new Zakazi();
        zakazi.setClName(cn);
        zakazi.setOrder(orderr);
        zakazi.setPricec(p);
        OrderActivity.myAppDatabase.myDao().updateZakazi(zakazi);
    }
});
        return view;

    }
```

Comment: Please post your `Entity` `Dao` and `Database`

Comment: @GGWP  Entity [link](https://pastebin.com/UAzNgYCf) Database [link](https://pastebin.com/xcNb53SR) Dao is in question (very first code)

Comment: the problem is solved: primary key was the reason if this bug

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are creating new object of `Zakazi` when you are going to update the data. So value of primary key id is not set in your object on which basis room database updating your record.

You have to update your code as below steps:
1. Fetch auto generated id of the `Zakazi` record using `getId()` in `update.setOnClickListener` in your first fragment
2. Pass that id instead of price, name and order.
3. Fetch the data in Zakazi object using the id you received in bundle in another fragment.
4. In `updateB.setOnClickListener` update the data in same object in which you fetch data from database instead of creating new one and then try to update record in room database by query `OrderActivity.myAppDatabase.myDao().updateZakazi(zakazi);`

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: you mean i should make method getZakazbyId(int id) and parce throigh array of Zakazi to find those where its id equals method parameter id (that means id from bundle) ?

Comment: No. Pass the selected id from fragment-1 to fragment-2 in bundle and in fragment-2 you have to get that id from getArguments method then after fetch data by calling getZakazbyId(id);  getZakazbyId(int id) method will be in your Dao file. So you do not have to parce through array and compare the id. You will get object of Zakaz from room database directly from id.

Comment: You are welcome @NuruddinGadjievCenteruvelir. If my answer has solved your problem then you can upvote and accept my answer. Thanks!